Is the category of undirected graphs an infinity-pretopos?
Theorem C2.2.8 in "Sketches of an Elephant" by P.T. Johnstone states that an $\infty$-pretopos with a separating set of objects is a topos. However, the category of undirected graphs seem to be an $\infty$-pretopos with a separating set of objects, which is not a topos.
By the category of undirected graphs I mean the category, whose objects are triples $(V, E, \nu)$, where $V$ is the set of vertices, $E$ is the set of edges and $\nu : E \to \binom{V}{2}$ maps an edge to its ends, a morphism $(E_x, V_x, \nu_x) \to (E_y, V_y, \nu_y)$ is a pair of functions $f_E : E_x \to E_y$ and $f_V : V_x \to V_y$, such that
$$
\nu_y \circ f_E = \binom{f_V}{2} \circ \nu_x
$$
($\binom{V}{2}$ denotes the set of unordered pairs of $V$ (including the pairs such as $\{x, x\}$) and $\binom{f}{2}$ denotes the action of the corresponding functor on functions).
The category of undirected graphs seems to be finitely-complete and cocomplete. Colimits, equalizers and a terminal object can be constructed by applying the corresponding limit or colimit to the vertex set and the edge set. A binary product of graphs $(V_a, E_a, \nu_a)$ and $(V_b, E_b, \nu_b)$ is the graph, whose vertex set is $V_a \times V_b$ and the edge set is:
$$
\{(v,(e_a, e_b)) \in \binom{V_a \times V_b}{2} \times (E_a \times E_b) \mid \nu_a(e_a) = \binom{\pi_a}{2}(v) \land \nu_b(e_b) = \binom{\pi_b}{2}(v)\},
$$
where $\pi_a : A \times B \to A$ and $\pi_b : A \times B \to B$ are cartesian product projections.
A subobject of a graph $(V, E, \nu)$ (a subgraph) is a pair of predicates $\phi_E : \mathcal{P}(E)$ and $\phi_V : \mathcal{P}(V)$, such that $\phi_E(e) \implies \binom{\phi_V}{2}(\nu(e))$, for any $e \in E$ ($\binom{\phi}{2} : \mathcal{P}(\binom{V}{2})$ denotes a predicate defined by $\binom{\phi}{2}(\{a, b\}) \iff \phi(a) \land \phi(b)$).
A preimage of a subgraph $(\phi, \psi)$ under a morphism $(f, g)$ is the subgraph $(f^*\phi, g^*\psi)$, where $f^*$ is the preimage functor in the category of sets. The preimage functor in the category of graphs seem to have both a left adjoint and a right adjoint. The left adjoint of the preimage functor under $(f, g)$ maps a subgraph $(\phi, \psi)$ into the subgraph $(\exists_f \phi, \exists_g \psi)$, where $\exists_f$ denotes the left adjoint of the preimage functor in the category of sets. The right adjoint of the preimage functor under $(f, g)$ maps a subgraph $(\phi, \psi)$ into the subgraph $(\forall_f \phi \cap \forall_f (\nu^* \binom{\psi}{2}), \forall_g \psi)$, where $\forall_f$ denotes the right adjoint of the preimage functor in the category of sets and $\nu$ is the map that maps edges of the domain into their ends.
Since the left adjoint of the preimage functor is computed componentwise, it satisfies the Beck-Chevalley condition and the Frobenius reciprocity, so the category of graphs is regular. Since it's cocomplete, it's effective regular. Since the preimage functor has a right adjoint and the category of graphs is cocomplete, it's a geometric category. Since the vertex set of a pullback is a pullback of vertex sets, a pullback of distinct injections of a coproduct is an empty graph, so the category of graph is $\infty$-positive. This means that the category of graphs is an $\infty$-pretopos.
The graph $U$ with one vertex and no edges and the graph $A$ with one edge and two vertices, which are the ends of the edge, form a separating set of the category of graphs, since the graph morphisms are defined by their action on vertices and edges.
The category of graphs is not topos, because the product functor does not preserve coequalizers. A coequalizer of the two morphisms $s, t : U \to A$ is the terminal graph $T$, but a coequalizer of the morphisms $A \times s, A \times t: A \times U \to A \times A$ is the graph with two parallel edges and not $A \times T \simeq A$.
Which of my assumptions is wrong?

Incidentally, the category does seem to have a subobject classifier: that would be the graph with two vertices $\bot,\top$; one loop on $\bot$; one edge between $\bot$ and $\top$; and two loops on $\top$.  (Of course, your argument that the category is not a topos is directly indicative of a failure to be cartesian closed.)

You did not check that the category of undirected graphs is exact, i.e. that every internal equivalence relation is a kernel pair. In fact, the internal equivalence relation on $A$ generated by $s,t\colon U\to A$ is already a counter-example: it is the union of the diagonal $\Delta\colon A\rightarrowtail A\times A$ and the full discrete subgraph $d(A\times A)\rightarrowtail A\times A$, but its quotient is the terminal map $A\to T$ with kernel pair all of $A\times A$, including the additional non-diagonal edge of $A\times A$.

There are a couple of explanations for this failure. First, by definition the category is the so-called Artin gluing of the functor ${-\choose 2}\colon\mathcal Set\to\mathcal Set$, i.e. the comma category $\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal Set},{-\choose 2}$. By a theorem of Wraith, this would be a topos if ${-\choose 2}$ preserved pullbacks, but it doesn't: the canonical comparison function from unordered pairs of a pullback to pullback of unordered pairs is always surjective but fails to be injective when there are distinct pairs $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ with $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=g(y_1)=g(y_2)$.
Second, this category admits a reflective full functor to the category of directed graphs equipped with a symmetry, i.e. with an involution sending directed edges to directed edges in the opposite direction.
This later category is a topos since it is the categeory of set-valued functors from the category with two objects $E$ and $V$ and three non-identity morphisms $s,t\colon E\rightrightarrows V$ and $\sigma\colon E\to E$ satisfying $\sigma^2=\mathrm{id}_E$ and $s\circ\sigma=t$. The full functor from undirected graphs simply splits every undirected non-loop edge into a pair of directed edges in opposite directions exchanged by the symmetry, and makes every loop a fixed point of the symmetry. The reflection is given by collapsing pairs of directed edges related by the symmetry into undirected edges.
If this reflection preserved finite limits, then the category of undirected graphs would be a topos. But it does not: the square of $T'$, the symmetric directed graph with one node and two loops exchanged by the symmetry, is the symmetric directed graph with two pairs of loops exchanged by the symmetry. But the reflection of the square is then the undirected graph with one node and two loops, while the reflections of $T'$ is the terminal undirected graph $T$ whose square is itself.
This also shows that goes wrong with the congruences: the coequalizer of $s,t\colon U\to A$ in the category of directed graphs equipped with a symmetry is $T'$, and its kernel pair is exactly the minimal internal relation described earlier. Applying the reflector to obtain the quotient in undirected graphs does not change the internal equivalence relation but changes the quotient to $T$ and the kernel pair to all of $A\times A$, thereby destroying exactness.
This shows what goes wrong with the product preserving the coequalizer. In the category of directed graphs with symmetry, the coequalizer of $s,t\colon U\rightrightarrows A$ is $T'$, and the coequalizer of $A\times s,A\times t\colon A\times U\to A\times A$ is indeed $A\times T'$. Applying the reflector preserves the latter coequalizer (since $A\times T'$ has two parallel edges, not loops), but modifies the former to be the terminal $A\to T$.

Do you also need $s \circ \sigma = t$?

It seems like in the topos you describe, there would be two different types of loops: one which is a single $E$-section which is a fixed point of $\sigma$, and one which is a pair of $E$-sections mapped to each other by $\sigma$.

(Also, the pair-of-$E$-sections version of a one-vertex, one-loop graph would have a nontrivial automorphism, which would be contrary to our expectations of such a graph.)

@DanielSchepler right, the issue is that undirected graphs are isomorphic to the full reflective subcategory of directed graphs with symmetry whose loops are fixed points for the symmetry, and the reflector does not preserve finite limits.
